# Properties of a set of all limit points

Tags: general-topology

Let $S'$ be the set of all limit points of a set $S$. Prove that $(A\cup B)'=A'\cup B'$.

Proof: Let $x\in (A\cup B)'$ then $x$ is a limit point of $A\cup B$. Then any deleted neighborhood $N'(x)\cap (A\cup B)\neq \varnothing$ then $(N'(x)\cap A)\cup(N'(x)\cap B)\neq \varnothing$. Hence $N'(x)\cap A\neq \varnothing$ or $N'(x)\cap B\neq \varnothing$. Then $x\in A'$ or $x\in B'$. Therefore $x\in A'\cup B'$ and $(A\cup B)'\subset A'\cup B'$

Let $x\in A'\cup B'$ then $x\in A'$ or $x\in B'$. It means than any deleted neighborhood $N'(x)\cap A\neq \varnothing$ or $N'(x)\cap B\neq \varnothing$. Then $(N'(x)\cap A)\cup(N'(x)\cap B)=N'(x)\cap (A\cup B)\neq \varnothing$. Then $x\in (A\cup B)'$. Therefore $A'\cup B'\subset (A\cup B)'$.

Corollary: $(\overline{E})'=E'$ where $\overline{E}=E\cup E'$.

By previous theorem we got $(\overline{E})'=(E\cup E')'=E'\cup E''$ but $E''\subset E'$ and $(\overline E)'=E'$

Is my proof true?

Comment: I think your proof is perfectly OK.

Comment: @Zhanxiong I am sure it is not.

Comment: Zhanxiong my proof is not OK.Initial i thought that it's true but after some time i understand that it's false.

Comment: Your question (especially  the inclusion $E''\subset E'$ inspired me to ask a [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1342018/75923) that might interest you.

Answer (score 1):

At least the first part is not okay. You prove: $$\text{for every deleted neighborhood of }x:N'(x)\cap A\neq\varnothing\text{ or } N'(x)\cap B\neq\varnothing$$
What you should prove is: $$\text{fedno }x: N'(x)\cap A\neq\varnothing\text{ or fedno }x:N'(x)\cap B\neq\varnothing$$

(fedno stands for "for every deleted neighborhood of")

Unfortunately I must go now. Later I will have a second look.

---

**Edit**

Let it be that $x\notin A'\cup B'$. Then $x\notin A'$ so it has a deleted neighborhood $N_{A}$ with $N_{A}\cap A=\varnothing$. Also $x\notin B'$ so it has a deleted neighborhood $N_{B}$ with $N_{B}\cap B=\varnothing$.

Then $N:=N_{A}\cap N_{B}$
is a deleted neighborhood of $x$ with $N\cap(A\cup B)=\varnothing$.
So we are entitled to conclude that $x\notin(A\cup B)'$.

Proved is
now: $x\notin A'\cup B'\implies x\notin(A\cup B)'$. This for an arbitrary $x$, so actually it has been shown that the complement of $A'\cup B'$ is a subset of the complement of $(A\cup B)'$

This is equivalent with the statement
$(A\cup B)'\subset A'\cup B'$.

Comment: I think I got the desired result. I can't understand what you mean. $N'(x)=N(x)\backslash \{x\}$ - is a deleted neighborhood of point $x$.

Comment: I thought about your post more than hour but I can't understand :(

Comment: Yeah I understood you. All $N'(x)$ must intersect A or all $N'(x)$ must intersect B. But how to get this?

Comment: See my edit for that.

Comment: drhab, I have one question. How to prove strictly if $x\notin A \Rightarrow x\notin B$ equivalent to $x\in B \Rightarrow x\in A$? I can't understand this

Comment: Do you understand $B\subset A\iff A^c\subset B^c$ (where $D^c$ denotes the complement of $D$)?

Comment: yes i understand this

Comment: $B\subset A$ is the statement that $x\in B\implies x\in A$ for each $x$ and $A^c\subset B^c$ is the statement that $x\notin A\implies x\notin B$ for each $x$. These statements are equivalent, as you say to understand.

Comment: drhab, thank you! I want ask you: Is the inclusion $A'\cup B'\subset (A\cup B)'$ and the Corollary true?

Comment: The inclusion is okay, but I have my doubts about the corollary. It might not be trivial to prove that $E''\subset  E'$. Uptil now I can only prove that under the extra condition that the topology is $T_1$. You could ask a new question on that. Again I must go now.

Comment: Inclusion $E''\subset E'$ is trivial because $E'$ is closed. So it contains all his limit points. Hence $E''\subset E'$. What do you think about it?

Comment: Do you have a proper proof that $E'$ is closed? Then you are right. Btw, we must close this discussion now.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much!